# Prints "XX"KB="YY"MB and "ZZ"KB

Tags: java

I am completing a course and asked to turn any number in KB into MB plus the rest in KB. it asks me to use the remain function. Not sure how to lay it out.

```
public class MegaByteConverter {

    public static void printMegaBytesandKiloBytes(int kiloBytes) {

        int Megabytes = Math.floorDiv(kiloBytes, 1024);
        int RemaniningKilobytes = kiloBytes % 1024;

    }


}
```

This is what I have so far.

Comment: As a side-note: usually variables start with a lower-case in Java. Therefore, "megabytes" would be a better name than "Megabytes". 

Also, "Math.floorDiv" is not needed here - kiloBytes already is an Integer, therefore divisions always round down anyway (an Integer cannot contain floating point information). Use "kiloBytes / 1024" instead.

Comment: `Math.floorDiv(kiloBytes, 1024)` can also be written as `kiloBytes / 1024` which uses **integer division**. Example `7 / 5  == 1`. And `n = (n / m)*m + (n % m).`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple implementation:

```
import java.util.*;
class MegaByteConverter
{
    public static void printMegaBytesandKiloBytes(int kiloBytes)
    {
        int Megabytes = kiloBytes / 1024;
        int RemainingKilobytes = kiloBytes % 1024;
        // Printing the result in required format
        System.out.printf("%dKB = %dMB and %dKB\n", kiloBytes, Megabytes, RemainingKilobytes);
    }
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        int kiloBytes1 = 100500; // 98MB and 148KB
        int kiloBytes2 = 248160; // 242MB and 352KB
        printMegaBytesandKiloBytes(kiloBytes1);
        printMegaBytesandKiloBytes(kiloBytes2);
    }
}
```

Output:
**100500KB = 98MB and 148KB**
**248160KB = 242MB and 352KB**

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do it would be:

```
public class MegaByteConverter {

    public static void printMegaBytesandKiloBytes(int kiloBytes) {

        int Megabytes = Math.floorDiv(kiloBytes, 1024);
        int RemaniningKilobytes = kiloBytes % 1024;
        
        System.out.printf("%dKB = %dMB and %dKB", kiloBytes, Megabytes, RemaniningKilobytes);
    }
}
```

This method inserts `int` variables inside the String where the '%d's are before printing

Answer (score 0):

All good so far, all you have to do is return the result as a string.

For example like this:

```
public class MegaByteConverter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(printMegaBytesandKiloBytes(32768));
        System.out.println(printMegaBytesandKiloBytes(65535));
    }

    public static String printMegaBytesandKiloBytes(int kiloBytes) {

        int megabytes = Math.floorDiv(kiloBytes, 1024);
        int remaniningKilobytes = kiloBytes % 1024;

        return kiloBytes + "KB = " + megabytes + "MB and " + remaniningKilobytes + "KB";
    }
}
```